# Elasticsearch curl: (7) couldn't connect to host

Tags: mongodb, curl, elasticsearch

I was trying out elastic search with mongodb.

I have followed steps from 
http://satishgandham.com/2012/09/a-complete-guide-to-integrating-mongodb-with-elastic-search/

But when I try to set index by

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/_river/mongodb/_meta' -d '
{
    "type": "mongodb",
    "mongodb": {
        "db": "smmc-dart",
        "collection": "smmc_collectionDetails"
    },
    "index": {
        "name": "caseName",
        "type": "string"
    }
}'
```

I'm getting error

```
curl: (7) couldn't connect to host
```

When I tried `http://localhost:9200/` on my browser it shows

```
{
  "status" : 200,
  "name" : "Nicholas Scratch",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "1.1.0",
    "build_hash" : "2181e113dea80b4a9e31e58e9686658a2d46e363",
    "build_timestamp" : "2014-03-25T15:59:51Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "4.7"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

I also tried this in terminal

```
curl -XGET http://10.20.4.220:9200/
```

It resulted

```
curl: (7) couldn't connect to host
```

Why is this happening and how to fix it.

Answer (score 6):

On my Mac OS X, I use  `127.0.0.1:9200/` instead of `http://localhost:9200/` cause I had the same problem.

I think that when you use the command the terminal replaces the localhost by it's IPv6 address and I'm not sure that curl supports that.

Please check and let me know.

Comment: I fixed it. It was due to lack of permission. I was able to run it with sudo.