# Elasticsearch: can't connect via curl, weird inconsistent behavior

Tags: curl, elasticsearch

I'm running Elasticsearch 1.3.4, freshly installed on Mac OS X 10.10 via Homebrew:

```
$ brew install elasticsearch
$ elasticsearch
```

Running `http://localhost:9200/_cluster/state` in the browser succeeds:

```
{
  "cluster_name": "elasticsearch_jbrukh",
  "version": 2,
  "master_node": "q6Jzcza_RwaVvc_1u95O1Q",
  "blocks": {},
  "nodes": {
    "q6Jzcza_RwaVvc_1u95O1Q": {
      "name": "Ethan Edwards",
      "transport_address": "inet[/127.0.0.1:9300]",
      "attributes": {}
    }
  },
  "metadata": {
    "templates": {},
    "indices": {}
  },
  "routing_table": {
    "indices": {}
  },
  "routing_nodes": {
    "unassigned": [],
    "nodes": {
      "q6Jzcza_RwaVvc_1u95O1Q": []
    }
  },
  "allocations": []
}
```

However, the following curl command fails:

```
$ curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/_cluster/state"
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 9200: Connection refused
```

Moreover, the curl command succeeds intermittently, but only AFTER that URL is hit from the browser, then it works one time and then starts to fail again with the above error.

How can I fix that ?

Comment: Before spending a lot of time looking into this error message, like I did, give the service about 1 minute to start up first before trying to diagnose what might be a non-existent problem. I found this was the case for my issues on m3.medium instance on AWS. Not for all issues, but may save some of you precious time.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As I answered before on a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23131220/elasticsearch-curl-7-couldnt-connect-to-host). On my Mac OS X, I use 127.0.0.1:9200/ instead of http://localhost:9200/ cause I had the same problem.

I think that when you use the command the terminal replaces the localhost by it's IPv6 address and I'm not sure that curl supports that.

Please check and let me know.

Comment: Yes, I can confirm this is the case. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem (OS X 10.10 & ES 1.3.4).

Quick solution is to force curl to use IPv4 with `--ipv4`

```
curl --ipv4 -XGET "http://localhost:9200/_cluster/state"
```

(at least for me it worked)

Permanent solution is to edit `/etc/hosts` and comment out this line

```
#fe80::1%lo0    localhost
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting a similar issue issue, but seems to be the other way around.

Elasticsearch appears to be listening on ipv6 but not ipv4. In order to force my client to speak to it (in my case the node js driver [1]), I found that the notation for ipv6 localhost is the only way to hit it: http://[::1]:9200.

[1] https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-js/